# Verify Records Before Updating in Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

Let's say I have 2 counties:

- A
- B

Each has it's own URL:

- www.A.com
- www.B.com

I have a stored procedure that accepts 3 variables to enable or disable the service to the URL.  The `@Enable` variable is required but the user can enter the `@County_Code` or `@WebserviceURL` variables - or both.  But if they enter both, I want to verify that the record exits in the database.

For example,

`EXEC [dbo].usp_webservice_change_status
@enable = 1,
@county_code = 'A',
@webserviceURL =  'www.A.com';`

should execute and update the Enable flag.

But if I execute with the following values, I would like to have an error returned  stating something to the effect that County A does not have a corresponding value of www.B.com.

`EXEC [dbo].usp_webservice_change_status
@enable = 1,
@county_code = 'A',
@webserviceURL =  'www.B.com';`

Here is the complete stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_webservice_change_status]
@enable AS BIT,
@county_code AS CHAR(2) = NULL,
@webserviceURL AS VARCHAR(4000) = NULL

AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF @enable IS NULL
            RAISERROR ('The value for @enable should not be null', 15, 1);
        IF ( @county_code IS NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NULL )
            RAISERROR ('The value for @county_code and @webserviceURL cannot both be null', 15, 1);

IF ( @county_code IS NOT NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NULL )

UPDATE dbo.webservice_config
SET [enable] = @enable,
    comments = CASE
                   WHEN @enable = 1 THEN 'Enabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                   ELSE 'Disabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
               END    
WHERE county_code = @county_code

ELSE IF (@county_code IS NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NOT NULL )

UPDATE dbo.webservice_config
SET [enable] = @enable,
    comments = CASE
                   WHEN @enable = 1 THEN 'Enabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                   ELSE 'Disabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
               END    
WHERE webservice_URL = @webserviceURL

ELSE IF ( @county_code IS NOT NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NOT NULL )

UPDATE dbo.webservice_config
SET [enable] = @enable,
    comments = CASE
                   WHEN @enable = 1 THEN 'Enabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                   ELSE 'Disabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
               END    
WHERE ( county_code = @county_code AND webservice_URL = @webserviceURL )

    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with another IF statement if I understand what you want correctly... just add these two lines at the bottom of your `PROCEDURE` just before your `END;`

```
IF(@@ROWCOUNT) < 1
RAISERROR('Nothing Updated Due to Non Matching Records',15,1)
```

So it will look like this

```
--all your other code
WHERE ( county_code = @county_code AND webservice_URL = @webserviceURL )
IF(@@ROWCOUNT) < 1
RAISERROR('Nothing Updated Due to Non Matching Records',15,1)
END;
```

You could also wrap the entire thing in another `IF` if you want

```
ELSE IF ( @county_code IS NOT NULL AND @webserviceURL IS NOT NULL )

    IF(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.webservice_config  WHERE county_code = @county_code AND webservice_URL = @webserviceURL) < 1
        RAISERROR('Nothing Updated Due to Non Matching Records',15,1)
    ELSE
        UPDATE dbo.webservice_config
        SET [enable] = @enable,
            comments = CASE
                           WHEN @enable = 1 THEN 'Enabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                           ELSE 'Disabled by ' + SUSER_SNAME()
                       END    
        WHERE ( county_code = @county_code AND webservice_URL = @webserviceURL )

END;
```

You could also use `EXISTS` and other syntax instead of what I used... just some examples.

Comment: No worries at all @MISNole